# How to create a bootable USB drive with portable VM support?

Tags: linux, usb, virtual-machine, bootable-media, portable

I want to use my USB SSD drive to use as a portable linux system. It should be able to boot directly as well as from a running Windows (POSIX would be a nice addition) system (probably via some portable VM software). The user data on the drive also should be accessible from other running systems without needing to boot the system on the SSD.

In fact, I search for something similar to [Live Linux USB Creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/home). I doesn't need to be one single software though. LiLi (as they call it) was updated four years ago, so I seek for some more up to date way of doing this.

Currently I'm running a Windows system, but I'd also accept answers requiring Linux software.

Answer (score 0):

Make your SSD bootable by formatting using the *Disks* utility in Linux.

By default, a linux system will discover the SSD but Windows wont read the SSD if it is formatted with a Linux FS

Comment: I know all that. I know how to make a live OS on an USB drive. What I want is a live system I can boot from a running Windows instance without restarting the computer.

Comment: Just implement a Virtual machine

Comment: How? I want the same system to be bootable native and as a VM.